# Search strings in json array column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, where-clause

I have this PostgreSQL table:

```
id | something
1  | ["something1", "something2", "something3"]
2  | ["something1"]
3  | ["something2", "something4"]
```

I am using this query to get all the datas having the string `something1` in the `something` column:

```
select * from my_table where (something)::jsonb ? 'something1'
```

How can i modify (or also there's a better way) this query to get all the datas that contains `something1 OR something2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?`:

```
where something::jsonb ? 'something1'
```

To check for several possible values, use `?|` against a text array:

```
where something::jsonb ?| array['something1', 'something2']
```

This checks if any value from the array exists in the jsonb array. If you want to check if *all* array elements exist in the jsonb payload, then use `?&` instead.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks man!

Comment: @aletede91 can you tell how to write same query in mysql with same scenario ?